TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRetinaScaling') - How to Resolve?
I'm working on image cropping using the latest Fabric.js. Initially, when a user adds an image to the canvas, I call the getImgPolarId() function and store the image data in the currentImg global variable. When the user double-clicks on the canvas, I call the applyCropToImage() function. In this function, I create a backgroundImg with the same state as currentImg, setting the original image as that backgroundImg. I then apply a clipPath to the original image. After clicking on the canvas, I generate a new image that includes only the clipped portion. When applying the crop again, I want to remove the base URL image from the canvas and use the original image again, but I'm encountering an error like...
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRetinaScaling')
    at klass.drawControls (fabric.js:18058:39)
    at klass._renderControls (fabric.js:15860:28)
    at klass.drawControls (fabric.js:12876:22)
    at klass.renderCanvas (fabric.js:9799:14)
    at klass.renderAll (fabric.js:12062:12)
    at klass.renderAndReset (fabric.js:9735:12)
    at timer (zone.js:2367:41)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10757:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10757:36)

// Initially add Image Element in canvas
  getImgPolaroid(image_details, uploadfrom = '', st: any = {}, stickerFrom: string = '') {
    var id, that = this;
    fabric.util.loadImage(image_details,  (imgObj) => {
        var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
        image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        image.set({
          left: that.utils.getCenterCoord(imgObj.width * scale, that.zoomWidthRef),
          top: that.utils.getCenterCoord(imgObj.height * scale, that.zoomHeightRef),
          angle: 0,
          padding: 0,
          hasRotatingPoint: true,
          peloas: 12,
          isLocked: false,
          id: this.generateUniqueId(),
          cornerSize: 15,
          cornerColor: '#00C3F9',
          cornerStyle: 'circle',
          lockScalingFlip: true,
          clipTo: null,
          excludeFromExport: false,
          transparentCorners: false,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          that.canvas.add(image);
          that.canvas.centerObject(image);
          this.canvas.setActiveObject(image);
          this.currentImg = image;
          that.canvas.renderAll();
        }, 500);

      }, null, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
      return id;
    }

// apply cropping functionality to image on double-clicks
applyCropToImage(image, activeobject) {

  // set background image same as a original
  var backgroundImg = new fabric.Image(image.getElement(), {

    left: this.getClippathleft - this.whatLeftDiff,
    top: this.getClippathtop - this.whatTopDiff,
    scaleX: image.scaleX,
    scaleY: image.scaleY,
    opacity: 0.3,
    selectable: true,
  });

  backgroundImg.setCoords();
  this.canvas.add(backgroundImg);

  var index = this.canvas.getObjects().indexOf(image);
  backgroundImg.moveTo(index);

  image.set({});

  const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: this.getClippathleft,
    top: this.getClippathtop,
    width: this.getClippathwidth,
    height: this.getClippathheight,
    cornerSize: 15,
    cornerColor: '#00C3F9',
    cornerStyle: 'circle',
    selectable: false,
    evented: true,
    absolutePositioned: true,
    type: 'crop',
    transparentCorners: false,
    centeredScaling: false,
    centeredRotation: true,
    lockScalingFlip: true,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    _controlsVisibility: {
      tl: true,
      tr: true,
      br: true,
      bl: true,
      ml: false,
      mt: false,
      mr: false,
      mb: false,
      mtr: false
    },
  });
  image.setCoords();
  rect.setCoords();

  image.clipPath = rect;
  this.canvas.setActiveObject(image.clipPath);
  this.canvas.on({
    'mouse:down': (e) => {

      this.whatLeftDiff = rect.left - image.left;
      this.whatTopDiff = rect.top - image.top;

      const newRect = image.clipPath;

      // Create a new image instance from cropped area
      var croppedImg = new Image();
      croppedImg.src = this.canvas.toDataURL({
        left: newRect.left,
        top: newRect.top,
        width: newRect.width,
        height: newRect.height,
      });

      croppedImg.onload = () => {
        this.canvas.remove(image);
        const newImage = new fabric.Image(croppedImg);
        newImage.left = newRect.left;
        newImage.top = newRect.top;
        newImage.isCroped = true;
        newImage.element_type = "stockphotos";
        newImage.cornerSize = 15;
        newImage.cornerColor = '#00C3F9';
        newImage.cornerStyle = 'circle';
        newImage.transparentCorners = false;
        newImage.setCoords();
        this.canvas.add(newImage);

        // Remove clip path and background image (optional)
        image.clipPath = null;
        this.canvas.remove(backgroundImg);
        this.canvas.renderAll();

      }

      this.canvas.renderAll();
    },
    this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
  })
}


Probably, an issue with fabric.js - https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/7321
